# Exibir somente semana com eventos Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, calendar

O [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) tem o botão de `Prev` e `Next` que avançam e voltam as semanas, se ficar avançando ele vai mostrando as semanas infinitamente, se voltar também.

Eu preciso de uma função que permita exibir somente as semanas que contém eventos marcados.

Por exemplo: Caso eu tenha um evento em 15/02/2014 e outro evento no dia 20/08/2015, os botões prev e next só poderão alternarem nestas duas semanas.

Alguém sabe de alguma função que permita fazer isto no fullcalendar?

Tentei procurar alguma função no docs do site do fullcalendar, más não encontrei nada disto, segue link: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Comment: poderia tentar que ao clicar no botão next e não haver mais eventos, o botão ser desabilitado. Veja no documentação a função que busca os eventos e o retorno dessa função. Se o retorno for 'null', você desabilita o botão.

Comment: [Essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943880/fullcalendar-eventlimit-for-agendaweek)  parece mostrar uma dificuldade em entender os eventos da biblioteca.

Comment: Resolvido, logo irei por o código aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue código:

segue js que pega data inicial e data final cadastrada e limita as setas de prv e next do fullcalendar:

```
viewRender: function(view,element) {
      var now = moment('<?php print $eventos_agenda[0]->data_clicada ?>');
        var end = moment('<?php print $eventos_agenda[$final]->data_clicada ?>');
                    if ( end < view.end) {
                       $("#botao_passa").addClass('disabled');
                    }
                    else {
                       $("#botao_passa").removeClass('disabled');
                    }
                    if ( view.start < now) {
                       $("#botao_volta").addClass('disabled');
                    }
                    else {
                       $("#botao_volta").removeClass('disabled');
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Então marque sua resposta como aceita. Obrigado.